# Python CSV parsing outputs inconsistent count

Tags: python, csv, parsing, math, text

I am trying to create a program that scans a directory for all text files, converts them each to a .csv, and counts the **unique** names from a certain column in each file.

Here's the code:

```
import csv
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file in files:
        if '.txt' in file:
            #Convert everything to csv files here
            txt_file = file
            report_name = file
            print(report_name,"names:")
            #REPLACE above with: txt_file = file (and all instances below)
            csv_file = r"mycsv.csv"
            #Removing informatory spaces at the top:
            n = 2
            nfirstlines = []
            with open(file) as f, open("parsed.txt", "w") as out:
                for x in range(n):
                    nfirstlines.append(next(f))
                for line in f:
                    out.write(line)
            #os.remove(file)
            modsum = sum(1 for line in open('parsed.txt'))
            print("Total names Found:",modsum)
            in_txt = csv.reader(open("parsed.txt", "rt"), delimiter = '\t')
            out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wt'))
            out_csv.writerows(in_txt)

            #PO Finder
            with open("mycsv.csv", "r") as csv_file:
                text_file = open('names.txt','w')
                csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                for lines in csv_reader:
                  #print(lines['Names'])#, lines['FullNames'])
                  text_file.write((str(lines['Names'])))
                  text_file.write("\n")
            text_file.close()
            modsum = sum(1 for line in open('names.txt'))
            print("Total names read from csv:",modsum)

            #Duplicate remover
            input_file = "names.txt"
            with open(input_file, "rb") as fp:
                lines = fp.readlines()
                new_lines = []
                for line in lines:
                    #- Strip white spaces
                    line = line.strip()
                    if line not in new_lines:
                        new_lines.append(line)
            output_file = "output.txt"
            with open(output_file, "wb") as fp:
                fp.write(b"\n".join(new_lines))
            modsum = sum(1 for line in open('output.txt'))
            print("Total Unique names:",modsum)
            os.remove("output.txt")
            os.remove("names.txt")
```

Note - I remove 2 lines from the top of the text file because there's an informative header, and I need the column names on top to be able to find the "Names" column.

Testing this program with three identical text files gives me this result:

```
File1.txt names:
Total names Found: 280
Total names read from csv: 231
Total Unique names: 222
File2.txt names:
Total names Found: 280
Total names read from csv: 279
Total Unique names: 269
File3.txt errors:
Total names Found: 280
Total names read from csv: 279
Total Unique names: 269
```

Obviously, the files being identical, the resulting *numbers* should all be identical with the correct 269 unique names.

Furthermore - the CSV and the parsed.txt won't delete after I run the program.
I would also like to be able to locate EITHER columns "Names" **or** "FullNames", whichever is present in the text file.

And one more caveat - I cannot use pandas or any external libraries, unfortunately.

I appreciate any help that can be provided!